# ruby slanger not working

Tags: php, ruby, pusher

I am trying to run slanger in order to use pusher-server api on my server.

I am using ruby 2.1.2 and my gem is 2.4.5

When I am triggering the following command:

```
slanger -v --appkey "mykey" --secret "mysecret"
```

I get these errors:

```
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/slanger-0.4.0/bin/slanger:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/slanger:23:in `load'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/slanger:23:in `<main>'
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install slanger ? Using bundler (a) or using `gem install` (b) ?

a. Run slanger using bundler: `bundle exec slanger -v --appkey "mykey" --secret "mysecret"`

b. Install bundler too: `gem install bundler`

Comment: I've tried the b. version, but i got another error:

/root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/slanger-0.4.0/bin/slanger:67:in `block in <top (required)>': invalid option: --appkey (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/slanger-0.4.0/bin/slanger:14:in `new'...

Could you help me with this too?